# Ion Tabs not appearing / acting as they should even on a blank page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have 2 tab bars currently in my app. Neither of them are working like what is shown in the Ionic Documentation for [tab bars](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs). The example at the side shows 3 tabs with `music` being the default selection. Both the icon and text are blue. Hovering over another tab will change its colour to blue. Clicking on that tab will make it permanently blue and the content of the page will change. However my tab bars do nothing. They don't have a click colour, highlight colour. Neither `onIonTabsDidChange`/`onIonTabsWillChange` are called. The tab bars just don't seem to work.

I've always assumed it is probably to do with all the `IonContents` and possibly them blocking click events and what not, so I thought I'd try a completely blank page with almost identical code to the example in the documentation. What I have is:

```
<IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
        <IonPage>
            <IonTabs>
                <IonRouterOutlet>

                </IonRouterOutlet>
                <IonTab tab="music">
                    <IonHeader translucent>
                        <IonToolbar>
                            <IonTitle>Music</IonTitle>
                        </IonToolbar>
                    </IonHeader>
                    <IonContent fullscreen>
                        <h1>Music</h1>
                    </IonContent>
                </IonTab>
                <IonTab tab="games">
                    <IonHeader translucent>
                        <IonToolbar>
                            <IonTitle>games</IonTitle>
                        </IonToolbar>
                    </IonHeader>
                    <IonContent fullscreen>
                        <h1>games</h1>
                    </IonContent>
                </IonTab>

                <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
                    <IonTabButton tab="music">
                        <IonLabel>Music</IonLabel>
                    </IonTabButton>
                    <IonTabButton tab="games">
                        <IonLabel>Games</IonLabel>
                    </IonTabButton>
                </IonTabBar>
            </IonTabs>
        </IonPage>
    </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

The only changes made are 1 less tab, no icons, an `IonRouterOutlet` which is for some reason not shown in any examples and `IonReactRouter` (which are necessary otherwise I get errors). I also tried with and without `IonPage` and it didn't make a difference.
I believe this is about as bare-bones as it can get and yet the tabs are still not working. Hovering doesn't do anything, clicking doesn't do anything and the content of the page isn't changed. It just shows up like this:
[image: page]

I must be missing something very obvious but I have no idea what it can be.

Comment: i suggest you start with the tabs template generated by the cli, this code you have here is incomplete

Comment: Apparently my comment wasn't posted. Anyway, I generated the default code and it worked. The issue was that I didn't have an href on the buttons because I don't need one. But adding one got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare the routes. You can do that inside IonRouterOutlet

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
    <Route path="/music" />
    <Route path="/games" />
<IonRouterOutlet />
```

Check `<Route>`'s documentation for more attributes: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/route

Comment: My original comment didn't post for some reason but basically the issue was I didn't have an href on the buttons so they didn't do anything. I don't actually need to route anywhere since I am using react-swipeable-views but thanks anyway!